# Stretch div 100% within Blueprint container

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I want to use the Blueprint CSS framework for this site I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/uaSe3/

It allows me to layout my website in a nice 24 column grid.

However I want the background on my sitemap-div to stretch 100% horisontally in the browser, like this:

[image: How do I get the div to fill 100%]

How would you go about this? Would the best solution be to put the sitemap-div outside the Blueprint container, or is there some kind of ninja CSS-trick that would allow me to do this without altering my markup?

Hope the above makes sense, any hints is highly appreciated :)

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/uaSe3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove it from the parent container.  There's no way using CSS to make that container behave as you need it to if you don't..

Comment: Roger. Thx for helping me out! :)